# Dialog not going to recent app list with the app in android when clicking on recent apps button in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

i added a dialog with my own layout.

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
```

when i am clicking on recent app button (hardware) in my phone, my app goes the recent app list but the dialog fragment not going with app to the recent list.

its still in **foreground** but the app is in **background**. i know we can close it in **onpause** method. but its only happening in **marshmellow**. in **4.4.2**(working) the dialog goes with app when clicking on recent app button.

Any specific reason why not in marshaallow? Can anyone please help me.

Comment: anyone knows about this.

Comment: have you found any solution ??